In Catholicism, is it OK to join a church in a different neighborhood if I don't like the local one?
I’ve attended several Masses at my local Catholic Church, but am not feeling fulfilled, and sometimes, it almost feels like I’m not even welcome. There is another Catholic Church one town away that I’m thinking about trying to attend. I’m wondering if this would be wrong because then I wouldn’t be supporting my local Catholic Church. Is it OK to join a Catholic Church in a different town than where I live?

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

In Catholicism, is it OK to join a church in a different neighborhood if I don't like the local one?
Canon Law has no restrictions on this, so you are free to attend mass at a Catholic parish that is more conducive to your spirituality.

Not many Catholics know this, but your real parish is the one whose territory includes your place of residence.
At least that is how the Code of Canon Law still sees it. But even with that built-in understanding of one’s territorial parish, canon law does not require you to register or attend Mass at the parish that is nearest to your home.
“Lay Catholics, a lot of pastors too, think that you register in a parish and that you become a parishioner by signing up and registering with the parish. … But strictly speaking, that’s not how the Code of Canon Law treats it,” said Msgr. Jason Gray, a canon lawyer and a priest of the Diocese of Peoria, Illinois.
“There is nothing that prohibits people from attending Mass wherever they wish to go. … Any Catholic can go to any Catholic church, satisfy their Sunday obligation, and the code really has nothing to say about that,” Msgr. Gray told Our Sunday Visitor.
That conflicting situation reflects a reality in the modern world. People today are much more mobile than what were earlier generations of Catholics. They can drive to parishes many miles away. Unlike their predecessors, Church leaders today would be hard-pressed to require Catholics to only attend Mass at their local parishes. - Addressing the phenomenon of parish hopping

In previous centuries, bishops would require Catholics to only attend Mass in their neighborhood parishes given the difficulty of travel in the days before automobiles and mass transit.
Canon Law states the following about parish boundaries:

Can. 518 As a general rule a parish is to be territorial, that is, one which includes all the Christian faithful of a certain territory. When it is expedient, however, personal parishes are to be established determined by reason of the rite, language, or nationality of the Christian faithful of some territory, or even for some other reason.

Although a parish is territorial, Canon Law thus envisions some reasons for not making the closest parish an obligation to attend!
Canon Law does not state which parish or parishes we may or may not attend, even habitually.

"given the difficulty of travel in the days before automobiles and mass transit." Was that the real reason? Churches used to be on every corner anyways, so it would be easy even to walk to a different parish.

@Geremia Having lived in Europe over 20 years, I would say no. Only big cities in the Middle Ages had many churches. I would venture to say that they were not on every corner. Even Rome had many churches, but not so any as to even come close as to say that there was one on every street corner. Many towns and villages simply had one parish church.

My main point is that it didn't have to do with transportation. It has to do with the priest knowing his flock better. Cf. Council of Trent, sess. 24, decree concerning reform ch. 13.

It may be permitted in current canon law, but it's not a good idea to hop from one parish to another because the priest cannot know his flock as well that way.
Council of Trent, sess. 24, decree concerning reform ch. 13:

in those cities and localities where the parochial churches have no definite boundaries, and whose rectors have not their own people whom they may rule but administer the sacraments indiscriminately to all who desire them, the holy council commands the bishops that, for the greater security of the salvation of the souls committed to them, they divide the people into definite and distinct parishes and assign to each its own and permanent parish priest, who can know his people and from whom alone they may licitly receive the sacraments;


For many years I have been signed up with a parish that I don't live in, though the church is the same distance from my home. It's even in a different diocese. I joined it because it was a great place for children and I stayed on because it was a wonderful supportive community. The priests in the area seem perfectly happy with such arrangements.

Generally speaking, you are member of a parish, and you should attend Mass in your parish. The organization of the Church is mainly geographical, parishes as part of a diocese, and the diocese being a certain part of the world. Opus Dei is a clear exception to that basic rule.
If you should think there are clear spiritual reasons to join another parish, I would suggest to discuss the matter with your confessor or maybe your bishop.
